# How do I drive 60 back-to-back LEDs (Christmas Lights)?

Tags: mosfet-driver

I would like to reuse some old LED strings. I hope to replace the (failed) original controller with an AVR chip, but I do not know how to construct the differential MOSFET driver stage.

The sketch below is not complete (as the string is in fact 5 blocks of 12 parallel LEDs) but my problem is finding a way to provide the alternating current necessary to light firstly the odd LEDs and then the even LEDs?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPkLgq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Have you considered just feeding it DC, lighting only half of the LEDs? I suspect brightness won't suffer, and overheating might also not be a problem. You'd need to check that though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are searching is a H bridge driver.

[image]

It's typically used in motor control application.

[Here](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14451) is perhaps something that can get you started with some good example [There](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/tb6612fng-hookup-guide?_ga=2.47036960.627273337.1542372506-1957131350.1537437087).

It is meant to drive motor, but will work the same with your LED. CW direction would be one LED type and CCW would be the other LED lighting up.

You also need to limit the current. Check whether those LED integrate the resistor (which is often the case in those led string). Otherwise you will also need current regulation.

Comment: For the LED application, you need different current control though, as the LEDs have less inductivity.

Comment: yes but the question ask how to provide "alternating current". I will edit the answer.